# Why Is My Array Index Out Of Range Using An If Statement?

Tags: ios, swift, uipickerview

This is the code:

```
func setTimeArray() {
    let iStart = Int(Double(selectedStart)! * 0.01)
    var index = iStart
    var tempArray: Array<String> = []

    print("count is ", count)
    for i in 0..<self.count  {
        var theHours = ""
        if (index == 24) {
           index = 0
        }  else if (index == 23) {
            theHours = self.parse24(theString: String(index)) + " to " + self.parse24(theString: "0")
        } else {
            theHours = self.parse24(theString: String(index)) + " to " + self.parse24(theString: String(index + 1))
        }
        tempArray.insert(theHours, at: i)
        index = index + 1
    }
    self.timeArray = tempArray
}
```

This code works just fine, but I need to wrap the place where it inserts into the tempArray so that it doesn't add an empty string. Unfortunately, when I try to add an if statement, or place tempArray.insert(theHours, at: i) inside the already existing if statements, I get the error: "Swift/Array.swift:405: Fatal error: Array index is out of range"

I mean, I'm actually adding more items without the if statement! Can anyone tell me how to fix this?

Comment: So you are trying to insert at the index which actually does not exist?

Comment: Not entirely clear what you are asking... you say *"This code works just fine..."* but you're not showing us what code does ***NOT*** work fine.

Comment: Oh sorry, I posted bad code. Look, I do this a lot, even though I've been trying to get good at this for years -- again, I'm sorry for messing up the archive. To clarify, the line "tempArray.insert(theHours, at: i)" actually works on an array without that index when it wasn't wrapped inside the if statements. It actually added new indices when with that line under index = index + i. It was basically affirming my false belief that I was using the correct method to push new elements to the array, which was causing a lot of confusion.

Comment: tempArray.insert(theHours, at: i) not "self.timeArray.append(theHours)"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you look at the [documentation of the insert function](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/3126951-insert), it says the following about the `i` parameter:

> `i`
>
> The position at which to insert the new element. `index` must be a valid index of the array or equal to its `endIndex` property.

You need to insert the element to an existing `index` or add it to the end of the array. It might help to add a print statement to print `index`, `i` and the array you are inserting it in to see what is exactly going on.

Comment: So apparently I am using it wrong. But why does it work unless its wrapped inside an if statement? Weird.

Comment: It's hard for me to exactly understand your code without more context. Perhaps elaborate a little in the opening post, show the code that is not working properly. Give an example of what you are expecting to happen, etc.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, and I really appreciate your patience and graciousness in trying to answer. I actually gave code that DID error out. The line "self.timeArray.append(theHours)" errors when its inside an if statement. When I place it outside of the if statements, right before the index = index + 1 line it actually works just fine. The fact that it was doing that basically affirmed my belief that I was using the correct method on the array and led to a lot of confusion. :)

Answer (score 0):

Still a bit confusing, but I *think* I understand what you're going for...

Suppose `count` is `5` ...

If it is 10 o'clock, you want an array result of:

```
[10:00 to 11:00]
[11:00 to 12:00]
[12:00 to 13:00]
[13:00 to 14:00]
[14:00 to 15:00]
```

If it is 15 o'clock, you want an array result of:

```
[15:00 to 16:00]
[16:00 to 17:00]
[17:00 to 18:00]
[18:00 to 19:00]
[19:00 to 20:00]
```

If it is ***22 o'clock***, you want it to "wrap around" and get an array result of:

```
[22:00 to 23:00]
[23:00 to 0:00]
[0:00 to 1:00]
[1:00 to 2:00]
[2:00 to 3:00]
```

(your `self.parse24(theString: String(index))` may be formatting it a little different).

If that's the case, take a look at this:

```
    var tempArray: Array<String> = []

    // no need for an "i" counter variable
    for _ in 0..<self.count  {
        var theHours = ""
        
        // if we're at 24, set index to 0
        if (index == 24) {
            index = 0
        }
        
        if (index == 23) {
            // if we're at 23, the string will be "23:00 to 0:00"
            theHours = "23:00 to 0:00"
        } else {
            // the string will be "index to index+1"
            theHours = "\(index):00 to \(index+1):00"
        }
        // don't use insert, just append the new string
        //tempArray.insert(theHours, at: i)
        tempArray.append(theHours)
        
        index = index + 1
    }
    
    self.timeArray = tempArray
```

---

**Edit**

It's probably important that you understand *why* you were getting the `Array index is out of range` error.

You still didn't post the code that was causing the error, but I'm guessing it is something like this:

```
    for i in 0..<self.count  {
        var theHours = ""
        if (index == 24) {
            index = 0
        }  else if (index == 23) {
            theHours = self.parse24(theString: String(index)) + " to " + self.parse24(theString: "0")
        } else {
            theHours = self.parse24(theString: String(index)) + " to " + self.parse24(theString: String(index + 1))
        }
        
        if theHours.isEmpty {
            // don't add the empty string to the array
        } else {
            // add it to the array
            tempArray.insert(theHours, at: i)
        }
        
        index = index + 1
    }
```

So, if we start at **22 o'clock**, and `count` equals `5`, your code does this:

```
i equals 0
index equals 22
theHours = "22 to 23"
insert string at [i]  // i is 0
increment index
increment i

i now equals 1
index now equals 23
theHours = "23 to 0"
insert string at [i]  // i is 1
increment index
increment i

i now equals 2
index now equals 24
    set index to 0
theHours = ""
DON'T insert empty string
increment i

i now equals 3
index now equals 0
theHours = "0 to 1"
insert string at [i]  // i is 3

*** ERROR ***
```

You get the out of range error because you ***didn't*** insert the empty string at [2], but `i` keeps incrementing.

Comment: Done, my friend. What was confusing the hell into me was that I was getting away with using tempArray.insert unless I put it in that if statement under the hours assignment. I thought I was doing the right thing because it was working outside the if statement. Still blows my mind...

Comment: @Lester - see the **Edit** to my answer. I think it's important that you understand this, so it no longer *"blows your mind"*.